# Android Biometric API Issue

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

**What I want to achieve:** Provide options to login with different biometrics like FingerPrint, FaceId and Iris. I want to give option of using PIN, Password or Pattern incase any biometric sensor doesn't work.

**Problem:** While user clicks on "**Use Password**" option it directly goes to the "**onAuthenticationError**" callback where I'm checking error code for **BiometricPrompt.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON**. My concern is, do I need to handle it by myself? I mean do I need to show a dialogPopUp where I will ask user to enter his/her email/username and password and then he/she can login in my app?

What I have done:

**dependency:**

```
implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.2.0-alpha01'
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var executor: Executor
    private lateinit var biometricPrompt: BiometricPrompt

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this)
        biometricPrompt = createBiometricObject()
    }

    private fun createBiometricObject(): BiometricPrompt {

        return BiometricPrompt(this, executor, object : AuthenticationCallback() {

            override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
                super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)

                if (errorCode == ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON && errString == "Use Password") {
                    // Do I need to create my own DialogPopUp?
                }
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                super.onAuthenticationFailed()
            }

            override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
                super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
            }
        })
    }

    fun loginWithBiometrics(view: View) {
        when (BiometricManager.from(this).canAuthenticate(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)) {
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_SUCCESS -> biometricPrompt.authenticate(
                createPromptInfoForBiometrics()
            )
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NONE_ENROLLED -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Please enroll your biometrics",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_NO_HARDWARE -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Device not compatible",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_HW_UNAVAILABLE -> Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Sensors are available as off now, please try again later!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
            ).show()
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_SECURITY_UPDATE_REQUIRED -> {
                TODO()
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED -> {
                TODO()
            }
            BiometricManager.BIOMETRIC_STATUS_UNKNOWN -> {
                biometricPrompt.authenticate(createPromptInfoForBiometrics())
            }
        }
    }

    private fun createPromptInfoForBiometrics(): BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo {
        return BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle("Biometric Login")
            .setSubtitle("Please login with your biometrics")
            .setNegativeButtonText("Use Password")
            .setAllowedAuthenticators(BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
            .build()
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Biometric has authentication types and these has special configuration(Class1, Class 2, Class 3 -> Default, WEAK, STRONG)-> https://source.android.com/compatibility/android-cdd#7_3_10_biometric_sensors

Comment: For my scenario which one should I use for _NEGATIVE BUTTON CLICK_?

Comment: i think it won't make difference , there is no relation between authenticators and negative  button

Comment: I think, you can use or you should understand how Authentication types works for your goal: "Provide options to login with different biometrics like FingerPrint, FaceId and Iris. I want to give option of using PIN, Password or Pattern incase any biometric sensor doesn't work."

Comment: But, For the specific scenario. Can you try  WEAK?

Comment: I had tried using WEAK, but no luck. Strange thing is I was using stable verion 1.0.1 and I was working perfectly fine in Android 9. But It did not work in Android 10.

Answer (score 2):

You should try pass `DEVICE_CREDENTIAL` flag to `setAllowedAuthenticators()`

```
BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
                .setTitle("Biometric login for my app")
                //..
                .setAllowedAuthenticators(DEVICE_CREDENTIAL or BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
                .build()
```

But also make sure you use it with appropriate android API level. According to docs:

> Note that not all combinations of authenticator types are supported
> prior to Android 11 (API 30). Specifically, DEVICE_CREDENTIAL alone is
> unsupported prior to API 30, and BIOMETRIC_STRONG | DEVICE_CREDENTIAL
> is unsupported on API 28-29. Setting an unsupported value on an
> affected Android version will result in an error when calling build().